# Tag file for CMake default keywords

Tags: tags, filetype-cmake

Is there any distribution of docs and tags file for CMake default keywords?

eg. I want to jump to description of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX or get_cmake_property() when viewing CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question fully. Maybe an example of input and more indication about what you want to achieve concretely would help.

Comment: You might have better luck asking the CMake community/developers